# How to enter a JtextField from another class

Tags: java, jdbc, jbutton, jtextfield

So what I'm trying to do is when I enter a **primary id** in a `JTextField` and click proceed, it will take that **primary id** and store it as a new record in another table.
What happens when you click proceed is that it takes you to another app where the **primary id** is display from the previous app.

My problem here is that it won't let me display the text. My error says:

```
non-static variable pat_id cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How do I bypass this?

Here is my code:

```
private void proceedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {

        String sql = "Insert into medicalRec (patient_id)" + " values (?)";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(pat_id.getText()));
        pst.execute();
        new medRec().setVisible(true);

        String sql2 = "select * from PATIENT where patient_id=?";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {

            String add0 = rs.getString("patient_id");
            medRec.pat_id.setText(add0);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line number is your exception on?

Comment: Look at following question could solve your problem by your own. [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: Also what is this `new medRec().setVisible(true);` looks like you are creating an instance of a `medRec` and immediately setting it visible without keeping any reference to the record.

Comment: @cogsmos sorry it's medRec.pat_id.setText (add0); , thats where i get an error, also the new medRec().setVis.... takes you to the new app, which I am glad to say is functional

Comment: have you initialized your JTextField in the other class? For example:
Class1{public static JTextField myText = new JTextField();} and then in the other class refer to it like Class1.myText.setText("something"); ?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here seems to be with your medRec class. Without seeing all the code I can bet that medRec is a class name and pat_id is an instance variable that looks something like this:

```
public class medRec {
     ...
     public JTextField pat_id = new JTextField();
     ...
     public void setVisible(boolean b){ ... }
}
```

This means that you should get an instance of the class first, save it as a variable and manipulate setVisible and pat_id on that such as this:

```
medRec mr = new medRec();
mr.setVisible(true);
mr.pat_id.setText("abc");
```